# Set precision for gnuplot data labels

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot data labels along with my box plot:

```
   plot ARG2 using 1:2 with boxes lc rgb "blue" notitle,\
    "" u 1:2:3 with labels notitle
```

The column `$3` has a precison of **8** decimal values, however I want to print only **3** decimal places.

I have tried using the floor function but it doesn't work:

```
"" u 1:2:(floor($3*1e3)/1e3) with labels notitle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot "whatever" using 1:2:(sprintf("%.3f",$3)) with labels
```

Comment: Thanks @Ethan.  Can you also tell me why `"" u 1:2:($2>0.000?sprintf("%.3f",$2): NaN)` meant to suppress '0' labels does not work?

Comment: `with labels` expects a string for the third parameter. NaN is not a string, it is a peculiar numerical value. You can think of it as meaning "an empty slot for a number".  You want intead "an empty slot for a string".  So `"" u 1:2:($2>0 ? sprintf("%.3f",$2) : "")`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ethan!